# Long equation in two column paper

Tags: equations, two-column

I'm writing a paper where two columns layout is required. I have pretty long equation which fortunately is too long to be put into one column.
This is my current solution:

```
\begin{equation}
  \label{simpleRule}
    \frac{S=<R,A,O>, P\in AFP (O), <R,A,P,E>\in Observed}{S\models \diamondsuit E} 
\end{equation}
```

any ideas how to make it suit two columns layout ?

Comment: What is the meaning of it? Is there a reason why you typeset it using `\frac`? Besides, are you sure you want to use `<` and `>` here, and not `\langle` and `\rangle`?

Comment: i think you mean "unfortunately" ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `\splitrule` macro of the `mathtools` package to split the numerator term into two parts. In the example below, that's what's done in the first equation. In the second equation, I suggest applying a few more modifications; adopt them as you see fit.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
With just \texttt{\textbackslash splitrule} applied:
\begin{equation}\label{simpleRule}
    \frac{\splitfrac{S=<R,A,O>, P\in AFP (O),}
           { <R,A,P,E>\in Observed}}
        {S\models \diamondsuit E}
\end{equation}
With a few more modifications applied:
\begin{equation}\label{notsosimpleRule}
    \frac{\splitfrac{S=\langle R,A,O\rangle, P\in \textit{AFP} (O),}
           { \langle R,A,P,E \rangle \in \textit{Observed}}}
        {S\models \diamondsuit E}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Finally, I can't help but comment on the fact that the letters in the second angle-brackets expression make for an extremely unpleasant -- and very likely utterly distracting -- word. Any chance you can come up either with a different ordering of the four letters or an entirely different set of four letters?

Comment: The word *RAPE* jumps at me when I look at the output :s

Comment: I'd upvote a second time if I could for suggesting rearranging the acronym.

Comment: I really like the version with your modifications. Thanks for that. btw. thanks for pointing out the acronym problem, I'll fix that!